# moment.js date comparison - day before today or two days after today?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm struggling with a moment.js "query" to figure out if a date (ex : 12/10/2014) is within the range of the day before "today", or two days after "today".

Been googling around, and checking the moment.js documentation, but haven't found any proper or understandable examples on how to do this...

Comment: Can you post your code with whatever errors or unexpected behaviour you're seeing?

Comment: [https://github.com/gf3/moment-range](https://github.com/gf3/moment-range) will do you work.

Comment: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/

Comment: Just what i was looking for Ninad. Thanks a bunch :)

Comment: Ninad : Can you answer the question so i ca accept it ?

Comment: @Ninad, OP was trying to get your attention. Terje, use "@" before their name so the site will notify them that someone's talking to them.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Using moment, you can do the following...

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.8.4/moment.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var now = moment(),
      begin = moment().subtract(1, 'days').startOf('day'),
      end = moment().add(2, 'days').endOf('day')

  document.write(now.isAfter(begin) && now.isBefore(end))
</script>
```

Answer (score 5):

As of `moment@2.15.1`, there is a `isBetween` method that allow to check if a date is between two dates, with inclusive and exclusive support.

Check http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-between/

**Example:**

`moment(dateToCheck).isBetween(startDate, endDate);`